# Is Functional Automation Testing worth the effort?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, functional-testing

Do you think that the effort which we put to automated functional tests really impacts?

As most of the time it considered as secondary option in many service based companies and when it comes to delivery, they rely on Manual testing.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer
**Yes**

Long answer (short version)
**Depends**

- if you have budget and time
- if you have people with necessary skills
- if you maintain the project in support or if this is a long project in order to reuse the automation suite
- how big the project is - in case you don't have enough time later to rerun all manual tests between important releases because there are too many features to cover or you don't have enough people
- you have repetitive tasks, project is stable and you don't have major changes with each release

---

I would say: Automate if you feel it brings value, this is a decision based on each project and team.

You have a lot of tools to choose from, even easy ones with record and play if you need a small suite and you don't have the skills for something complex.

Answer (score 0):

**Automated Functional Test Really Impacts?**
I would say Yes.

However, its coverage is not as wide as manual testing. Service based company will prefer to use manual testing as they will need to perform a lot of exploratory testing. Just to make sure that there's no introduced issue on the other (possibly) affected area. In my opinion, that kind of testing is not fully supported by automated testing. Unless you have a lot of test cases - which might affect the software maintenance/development cost.

I think regression testing is good for regression testing - to avoid repetitive works for software tester. As in my experience, regression testing will executing the same end-to-end test case.